# What to put in stead of "ctx.voice_client" in "interaction:discord.Interaction"

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Here is code to disconnect the bot from vc. But it shows this error
*AttributeError: 'Interaction' object has no attribute 'voice_client'*
I looked at `https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/` and tried to add it manually but it doesn't work.

```
@bot.tree.command(name="disconnect", description="Disconnect from a vc",guild=guild)
async def disconnect(ctx: commands.Context):
    if not ctx.client:
        return await ctx.send("I am not in vc")
    elif not ctx.user.voice:
        return await ctx.send("You are not in vc")
    else:
        vc: wavelink.Player = ctx.client
    
    await vc.disconnect()
    vc.queue.clear()
    await ctx.send("Bye-bye")
```

Comment: What documentation have you looked at/what have you tried? Please [edit] these details into your question.

Comment: Do you _really_ need to use that language when asking for help?

Comment: ye cos it's written in python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer create `guild = Interaction.guild` and then user this `guild.voice_client`

Comment: A simpler answer would be `interaction.guild.voice_client`.

Answer (score 0):

The `bot.tree.command` decorator's first parameter in the function given isn't `commands.Context`, it's `discord.Interaction` as your error is telling you

Comment: So it must look like this ? `async def disconnect(ctx: discord.Interaction)`

Comment: I mean sure, you can name it whatever you want, though you need to check documentation and make sure you're accessing the correct attributes.

Comment: In docs about voice_client is said nothing here is the docs `https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html`